# Send result of sql query in email using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, azure-runbook

I am trying to send the results of an av SQL query in an email using PowerShell through Azure Runbook. The SQL query works and the results prints to the console but it won't print in an email. Instead, I get the following text in my email "System.Data.DataRow". The connection with my DB works fine and it outputs to the console just doesn't print in an email.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$SqlQuery = "SELECT
          SUM([Cost]) AS [Sum Cost]
      FROM [dbo].[TestData]
      ;"

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)  
    $DataSet.Tables[0]

Send-MailMessage -From "me@gmail.com" -To "you@gmail.com" -Subject "Sum cost" -Body "This is the Sum Cost: $($DataSet.Tables[0])" -SmtpServer mail.net -Credential $Cred -Port $Eport
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there's no defined way in the system to turn a DataTable into a string. That means you have to do it.

You could do something like this:

```
$Body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Html -As Table
```

Or something like this to format it as a table or list and then stringify that output:

```
$Body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
```

There are caveats and problems with both approaches, like the default formatting on the HTML table is pretty terrible and `Format-Table` has a max width that can be difficult to overcome, but this method is generally what you need to use.

---

Alternately, if your query truly returns a single row with a single column, you could easily just pull the data yourself out of the DataSet:

```
$SumCost =  $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].'Sum Cost'

Send-MailMessage -From "me@gmail.com" -To "you@gmail.com" -Subject "Sum cost" -Body "This is the Sum Cost: $SumCost" -SmtpServer mail.net -Credential $Cred -Port $Eport
```

Or, if it really is that simple, you could [use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar) instead of messing around with the DataSet and DataAdapter entirely. ExecuteScalar is designed to just return the first column of the first row of the result set and that's it. Then you can just do:

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery

try {
    $SqlConnection.Open()
    $SumCost = $SqlCmd.ExecuteScalar()
}
finally {
    $SqlConnection.Dispose()
}
```

And `$SumCost` should just be your value.